# S3 vs. EBS Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What are the performance implications of using S3 vs. EBS?

Say my app needs to access files fast. Will EBS be much faster than S3? I would like to use S3 because I don't want a space limitations, but am worried about performance.

Answer (score 3):

In general EBS will perform better than S3 (EBS has 4 variations - gp2, io1, st1, sc1). With io1 you get to specify IOPS capabilities (S3 has no user specified performance control). gp2 has IO bursts (up to 3000 IOPS) and IO credits (5.4 Million) which may be good for some applications. Check out http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-maximizing-ec2-and-ebs-performance

Hope it is understood that both use different access methods. S3 is an object store, EBS is a block storage.

(Please also note that EBS is also network attached, not directly attached to EC as far as I know)

Answer (score 2):

This should help:
[image]

Regards,
Aditya Garg

Comment: This looks helpful. My gutfeeling says it might be (even) more appreciated if you turn it into text.

Comment: Please read up on table formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). Not all users are able to see images.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the AWS Elastic File System as an alternative to S3 and EBS. Its speed will likely fall between S3 and EBS but it does provide ways to control performance and it is not limited in terms of size. Amazon EFS Performance details: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html

Answer (score 0):

EBS will always be more faster if you compare EBS vs S3 for data transfer, as EBS is directly attached to the EC2 instance. But again the storage limitation comes in picture for EBS.

So if you want to achieve both less latency and unlimited storage, I will suggest attaching S3 bucket as a volume to your EC2 instance, gave a very good data transfer speeds in my case.

Here is a guide that is really good for achieving.

https://fullstacknotes.com/mount-aws-s3-bucket-to-ubuntu-file-system/

Comment: That isn't going to be anywhere near as fast as EBS, especially when compared to a provisioned IOPS volume connected to an EBS optimized instance.

Comment: User is aaking for unlimited storage too